# How to pass Age Verification with DOM

Tags: php, image, dom, cookies, curl

I'm attempting to pull some image URLs from Steam store pages, such as:
http://store.steampowered.com/app/35700/
http://store.steampowered.com/app/252490/

Here's the code I'm using:

```
$url = 'http://store.steampowered.com/app/35700/';
$html = file_get_contents($url);
$dom = new domDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$images = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img');
foreach ($images as $image) {
  echo $image->getAttribute('src');
}
```

It works fine with the first store page, but the second one redirects to an age verification page, and the script returns the images from there. I need a way for the script to get past the age verification and access the actual store page.

Any help would be appreciated.

Edit:

This is what's passed to the server when the age form is submitted:

```
snr=1_agecheck_agecheck__age-gate&ageDay=1&ageMonth=January&ageYear=1979
```

and the cookies that it sets:

```
lastagecheckage=1-January-1979; expires=Tue, 03 Mar 2015 19:53:42 GMT; path=/; domain=store.steampowered.com
birthtime=662716801; path=/; domain=store.steampowered.com
```

Edit2:

I can set the cookies using cURL but they aren't used by DOM loadHTML, so I get the same result as before. I need either a way for loadHTML to use specific cookies that I set, or another method of grabbing the image URLs that will use cookies set by cURL.

Comment: I'd imagine that you pass a specific value which you can dig up through firebug or the like, as long as it isn't dynamic, and then you have your api call to be allowed to follow redirects.

Comment: I found the code for the age check form, and also the cookie that it sets, but i don't know where to go from there. (Edited main post with the info)

Comment: You will likely need to use something like cURL to handle getting the cookies, and then storing them for use in the second request.

Comment: I can set the cookies with cURL but I have no idea how to allow the loadHTML request to use them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solved! Here's the working code:

```
$url = 'http://store.steampowered.com/app/35700/';

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, "birthtime=28801; path=/; domain=store.steampowered.com");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$result = curl_exec($ch);

$dom = new domDocument;
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHTML($result);
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;

$images = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img');
foreach ($images as $image) {
  $src = $image->getAttribute('src');
  echo $src.PHP_EOL;
}

curl_close($ch);
```

Answer (score 4):

You were looking for php answers, but I was trying to do the same thing in python and this was the most relevant question. Your php answer helped me out so maybe a python solution will help someone. My solution using [python-requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#cookies) in Python 2.7:

```
    import requests

    url = 'http://store.steampowered.com/app/252490/'
    cookie = {
            'birthtime' : '28801',
            'path' : '/',
            'domain' : 'store.steampowered.com'
            }

    r = requests.get(url, cookies=cookie)
    assert (r.status_code == 200 and r.text.find('Please enter your birth date to continue') < 0), ("Failed to retrieve page for {url}. Error={code}.".format(url=url, code=r.status_code))

    print r.text.encode('utf-8')
```