# C# WPF Steam Website age verification skip

Tags: c#, wpf, webclient, steam

I am trying to download the html code from any steam game on their website from an application using this code.

```
WebClient web = new WebClient();
web.BaseAddress = "http://store.steampowered.com/app/" + gameID;
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(System.IO.Path.GetPathRoot(Environment.SystemDirectory) + "\\errorLog\\error.txt");
sw.Write(web.DownloadString(web.BaseAddress));
sw.Close();`
```

Although this works for some games not all work due to an age check that blocks and redirects me.

I've tried researching but haven't been able to find any info.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can utilize the unofficial [Storefront API](https://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/User:RJackson/StorefrontAPI) and the [`appdetails`](https://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/User:RJackson/StorefrontAPI#appdetails) call to gather information about a Steam game. It does not require an age check.

The basic URL you will call has this format

```
http://store.steampowered.com/api/appdetails/?appids=<APPID>&filters=basic
```

Replace `<APPID>` with the numeric application ID on the Steam store. The `filters` I've provided (`basic`) returns this data:

```
type
name
steam_appid
required_age
dlc
detailed_description
about_the_game
supported_languages
detailed_description
supported_languages
header_image
website
pc_requirements
mac_requirements
linux_requirements
```

If you want to see everything available, remove the `filters` from the URL.

Comment: Thank you this is a great help.

Answer (score 0):

To bypass the age check, you can provide a cookie with your request. See the cookie set in your browser when you submit your birthday.

More detail on this question:
[How to pass Age Verification with DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22140197/79125)